# Most used/valuable unit testing for Grails

Tags: grails, groovy

Currently I'm looking into unit tests for a Grails project I'm working on. I've heard some people use Spock, and some just create 'unit tests' but I'm unsure which direction is the correct direction. The Spock framework plugin for Grails hasn't been updated in almost 2 years now and I'm not sure if that's the proper direction to go.

Any suggestions for unit testing in Grails?

Comment: It sounds like you may be confused. It isn't Spock OR unit tests. We advocate using Spock for your unit tests.

Comment: Ah I see. I've seen Spock in the documentation for Grails, but I wasn't sure which approach to take. I would assume that if it's in the documentation, you would advocate it. (And that's the case!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest looking at what the Grails team itself uses to test Grails. You will find that they use Spock. However, that said, pick what works best for you.